# When do two unbounded operators commute ?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space and let $A,B$ be two unbounded, densley defined self-adjoint operators on $\mathcal H$ with $dom(A) = ran(A) = dom(B) = ran(B)$. Then both $AB$ and $BA$ are unbounded, densley defined operators with the same domain, so $$AB - BA$$ is again an unbounded, densely defined operator.

**Question: Are the following statements equivalent ?**

**a) $AB - BA = 0$**

**b) For any bounded borel function $\phi$ over $\mathbb R$, $F_A$ the *Borel functional calculus* of $A$, and any $x \in Dom(B)$, we have 
$[F_A(\phi)B - BF_A(\phi)](x) = 0$.**

The analogue statement for *bounded operators* is an immediate consequence of the spectral theorem. However, I don't quite see how to generalize the statement to the unbounded case, since the operator $A$ is only indirectly "seen" by its functional calculus $F_A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

First of all, $dom A=ran A$ can hold only for bounded self-adjoint operators.

The statement b) in your question implies the so-called **strong** commutativity of $A$ and $B$, in particular, that the unitary operators $e^{iA}$ and $e^{iB}$ commute.

In the book by Reed, Simon "Methods of mathematical physics" vol.1, chapter 8 there is an example of self-adjoint operators, such that $AB=BA$ holds on the common domain, but exponentials $e^{iA},e^{iB}$ do **not** commute.

Comment: I realize that my question is not well-posed, but since you already posted your answer, I shouldn't change it. In my concrete example, I was looking at $H$ the L^2-completion of the *total* de Rham complex of a closed Riemannain manifold. Here, $A = \Delta_*$ is the *total* Laplacian and $B = \delta_*$ the total differential. Only $A$ is self-adjoint, but $A$ and $B$ are both defined on a dense subdomain (the smooth forms), on which $AB = BA$ (so that $Ran(A) \subset Dom(A) = Dom(B)$ and $Ran(B) \subset Dom(B)$).